# Obter Dominio para um website inacabado

Tags: php, html, phpmailer, smtp, domínio

Boas pessoal, eu estou a construir um website e precisava de arranjar já um domínio para tratar da página de contactos, mais propriamente dos emails.

O problema é o seguinte, estou a usar o phpmailer e quero que o utilizador possa comunicar com o "dono" do website, ou seja, por exemplo, um email qualquer teste@gmail.com iria receber/gerir todos os emails provenientes dos utilizadores.

Contudo ao utilizar o SMTP da gmail (único que encontrei "free"), dá-me uma enormidade de erros que penso ser por permissões.

Já tentei o "Postmarapp", mas o problema é que eles pedem domínio do website, coisa que ainda não tenho, porque, o mesmo ainda se encontra em construção.

Portanto queria saber se é possível arranjar o tal domínio antes de terminar.

Deixo também aqui o código (form HTML e php) que tenho utilizado. (P.S: SMTP do gmail)

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputname3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nome</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputname3" placeholder="Nome" name="sendName">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email" name="sendEmail">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPass3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPass3" placeholder="Password Email" name="sendPass">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputAssunto3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Assunto</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAssunto3" placeholder="Assunto" name="sendSubject">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputMessage3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Mensagem</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <textarea placeholder="Escreva aqui a sua mensagem*" id="inputMessage3" name="sendMessage"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="send">Enviar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>


$name = $_POST['sendName'];
$email = $_POST['sendEmail'];
$subject = $_POST['sendSubject'];
$message = $_POST['sendMessage'];
$password = $_POST['sendPass'];

require_once('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
require_once('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
require_once('phpmailer/class.smtp.php');

define('GUSER', $email);
define('GPWD', $password);

$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
//$mail->Priority = 1; // Highest priority - Email priority (1 = High, 3 = Normal, 5 = low)
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';'smtp.live.com';
$mail->Port = 465; // or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = GUSER;
$mail->Password = GPWD;
$mail->From = $email;
$mail->msgHTML($message);
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = $message;
$mail->SetFrom($email,$name);
$mail->AddAddress("teste2x2016@gmail.com","Joao");
$mail->AddReplyTo($email,$name);

if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo "Message has been sent";
}
```

Comment: Parece não ter sentido algum. Poste os erros que recebe quando tenta enviar email pelo smtp do gmail.  Normalmente para envio de email não existe isso de precisar de um domínio.

Comment: Se utilizar o smtp do gmail nao é necessario mas se utilizar o postmarkapp é necessario dominio

Comment: mas são coisas distintas...  postmark é uma api (webservice terceirizado) e deve seguir as normas de uso da api..  Afinal, quer usar a api ou uma library como phmailer, swiftmailer, etc?

Comment: Eu quando chegar a casa posto os erros que me aparecem usando o smtp do gmail

Comment: @DanielOmine esta aqui os erro que me aparece quando por exemplo quero que o "From" seja de um hotmail por exemplo :

Comment: 2016-09-14 19:42:16 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost 2016-09-14 19:42:16 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN 2016-09-14 19:42:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: YWRyaWFuby5yLnIuZi5tQGhvdG1haWwuY29t 2016-09-14 19:42:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: aWJyYXRvcnJlczEw 2016-09-14 19:42:17 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials va3sm5661174wjb.18 - gsmtp 2016-09-14 19:42:17 SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. 2016-09-14 19:42:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT 2016-09-14 19:42:17 SMTP connect() failed.

Comment: Não é permitido setar um `From` diferente do email usado na autenticação. Atualmente praticamente todos os serviços de email bloqueiam. Na diretiva `From`, coloque o mesmo email que está usando para autenticação e então verás que funciona.

Comment: Mas eu estou a passar o mesmo email no From, ou seja, o utilizador tem o form de contacto onde insere o seu nome o seu email a pass do seu email e a mensagem e depois envia para outro email que eu criei que rwcebera fara a gestao de todos os emails do site recwbera todos os emails

Comment: mas aí é pior ainda.. rsrsrs.. se o usuário inserir email que não é do gmail, o gmail não vai autenticar.. Inclusive, essa mensagem de erro que vc postou está dizendo isso bem claro, que não aceita esse usuario e senha.. O SMTP do gmail não é um webservice onde pode inserir qualquer email para autenticar.. Para autenticar precisa setar uma conta @gmail.com. E o "From" como citei, precisa ser igual ao email usado na autenticação.

Comment: Ha alguma maneira de superar este problema? E que preciso que funcione para todoa os emails....

Comment: Basta definir uma conta do gmail para autenticação, conforme comentei repetidas vezes nos comentários acima. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=gmail+phpmailer

Comment: Ok obrigado irei tentar depois digo alguma coisa obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: O problema consiste que ele esta usando os dados do usuário (email | password) para usar no seu PHPMailer. Isso nunca vai dar certo você tem que usar suas credenciais do Gmail para fazer isso. Conforme expliquei em minha resposta você tem que usar as credenciais do seu Gmail (email | senha) para que as informações digitadas pelo usuário sejam enviadas para você o.O !!!

Comment: Ok isso eu ja tentei e funciona como ja tinha explicado no post em cima, contudo , depois ao receber o email e como se tivesse enviado de mim para mim porque o from fica com o mesmo email que rwcebeu..... A unica solucao seria passar o email do "sender" no assunto nao???? Ou ha outra solucao?

Comment: ok como disse anteriormente isso não é possivel pq e como se enviasse mensagem de mim para mim.... logo terei de usar o "AddReplayTo", muito obrigado pela ajuda , os dois

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para usar o `smtp` do Gmail usando PHPMailer o procedimento ocorre de duas maneiras:

- **primeira:** menos segura (usada em localhost durante o desenvolvimento ou em dominios sem certificado): "Ativar acesso a apps menos seguros" em sua conta goolgle você deve ir a página de configurações => ir a guia de segurança e ao chegar em *Desativar acesso a apps menos seguros* ativar o acesso. O caminho ais curto via navegador seria (estando logado em sua conta) "https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps" e ativar acesso.
- **segunda:** mais seguro e recomendado: usar um dominio com SSL/TLS. Observe que Gmail utiliza a porta 465 para conexões com certificados SSL e 587 pata certificados TLS caso não use uma conexão certificada deve-se usar o **aspmx.l.google.com** na porta 25 más isso restringe ao envio apenas para emails do Gmail.

Eu uso de boa para o desenvolvimento em localhost o PHPMailer funciona tranquilo mesmo com um certificado auto-assinado, como seu caso (ao que me parece) já possuir um dominio (?) pois quer enviar emails apartir da pagina de contato, recomendo este link para [dar uma olhada](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=pt-BR).

Caso não queira seguir nem a primeira nem a segunda opção descrita outro caminho é possivel.

Para isto tera de criar um app para usar autenticação (XOAUTH2) e na sua configuração PHPMailer adicionar a chave de autenticação.

Um passo-a-passo básico provido pelo próprio repositório PHPMailer:

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Using-Gmail-with-XOAUTH2

E é claro dar uma olhada na pasta de exemplos do seu PHPMAiler de como usar o xoauth do google ou:

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail_xoauth.phps

Caso tenha errors retorne a descrição.

Comment: Desde ja obrigado pela resposta. Tanto utilizando ssl ou tls retorna sempre erros ( como pode ver em cima nos comentarios do post). Passo o email, seja do outlook ou gmail, e respetiva pass e retorna sempre erros como podes ver em cima.... Eu acho que podera estr ligado a permissões

Comment: Bom seu erro relata que foi um erro no password... voçê esta usando smtp para receber para sua conta Gmail ou retransmitir para outra conta? Se for retransmisão aconselho a olhar o link que indiquei olhar. Lá fala coo usar o smtp com mais detalhes técnicos.

Comment: O que estou a fazer ou a tentar é o seguinte: uma pessoa entra no website e tem o formulario de concto onde dica o seu nome email password do seu email assunto e mensagem e esse email sera enviado para um que eu criei que recebera todos.... O que criei e do gmail ou seja e por exemplo teste@gmail.com

Comment: Me desculpe se eu estiver errado mas, você não pode usar sua página de contato para aceder a conta de outra pessoa. O seu php (no PHPMailer) deve conter os dados de sua conta não de quem esta entrando em contato com você. Supondo como você acabou de disser "entra no website e tem o formulario de concto onde dica o seu nome email password do seu email assunto e mensagem" se for realmente isso que você esta fazendo vai dar mesmo um erro o.O !?!